# Setting Context Item position in Firefox addons SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing an extension that involving adding an item to Firefox's context menu, but it appends to the end of the menu and I couldn't find any pointers customizing item's position using Addon SDK (insertBefore/insertAfter), I know how this can be done using XUL, but I'm trying to do it using Addon SDK or some sort of Addon SDK/XUL combination

This is the code snippet related to context menu

main.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.youtube.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js"),
  onAttach: function (worker) {
    worker.port.emit('link', data.url('convertbutton.png'));
}});

cm.Item({
  label: "Convert File",
  image: data.url("bighdconverterlogo128png.png"),
    context: [
    cm.URLContext(["*.youtube.com"]),
    cm.PageContext()
  ],
  contentScriptFile: data.url("menu.js"),
onMessage: function(vUrl){
        tabs.open(vUrl);
    }
});
```

data/menu.js

```
self.on("click", function(){
self.postMessage('http://hdconverter.co/' + 'c.php?url=' + window.location.href);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about sdk but for non-sdk addons its easy. but because you dont have the boiler plate setup its going to look long. add this code to your addon at the bottom:

```
var positionToInsertMenu = 0; //set the position you want it at here
var myLabelText = 'Convert File';

const {interfaces: Ci,utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

/*start - windowlistener*/
var windowListener = {
    //DO NOT EDIT HERE
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener("load", function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, false);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
    register: function () {
        // Load into any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        // Listen to new windows
        Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
    },
    unregister: function () {
        // Unload from any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.unloadFromWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        //Stop listening so future added windows dont get this attached
        Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
    },
    //END - DO NOT EDIT HERE
    loadIntoWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        var contentAreaContextMenu = aDOMWindow.document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu');
        var myMenuItem;
        if (contentAreaContextMenu) {
            var menuItems = contentAreaContextMenu.querySelector('menuitem');
            [].forEach.call(menuItems, function(item) {
                if (item.getAttribute('label') == myLabelText) {
                    myMenuItem = item;
                }
            });
            contentAreaContextMenu.removeChild(myMenuItem);
            if (contentAreaContextMenu.childNodes.length >= positionToInsertMenu) { //position is greater then number of childNodes so append to end
                contentAreaContextMenu.appendChild(myMenuItem);
            } else {
                contentAreaContextMenu.insertBefore(myMenuItem, contentAreaContextMenu.childNodes[thePosition]);
            }
        }
    },
    unloadFromWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        var myMenuItem = aDOMWindow.document.getElementById('myMenuItem');
        if (myMenuItem) {
            myMenuItem.parentNode.removeChild(myMenuItem);
        }
    }
};
windowListener.register();
```

on unload of your addon add this:

```
windowListener.unregister();
```

i copied pasted from a template and modded it real fast. for position to be accurate you probably have to consider which menuitems are hidden and which are not

Comment: You mean I have to rewrite non Addon SDK extension?

Comment: U dont have to. U can just copy that bit I gave you and paste it at botton of your sdk code. Note tho that this code is only repositioning 1 menuitem, if you want it do more, or a non-menu item like seperator, let me know and ill hook it up.